# Git conflict on pull request

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I have a branch called backend_setup where I am setting up the server and database. I pushed from the branch just fine but when making a pull request, I get "This branch has conflicts that must be resolved" which then lists `package-lock.json` and `package.json`. Searching for a solution only gets me people who had conflicts in the terminal. Mine let me add, commit, and push just fine but the pull request on github doesn't go through.

The conflict on my package-lock.json

```
<<<<<<< backend_setup
    "dotenv": {
      "version": "4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/dotenv/-/dotenv-4.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-hk7xN5rO1Vzm+V3r7NzhefegzR0="
    },
=======
>>>>>>> master
```

and package.json

```
<<<<<<< backend_setup
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
=======
>>>>>>> master
```

Comment: Update both local branches and merge locally, then push and you should be able to merge the pull request.

Comment: I used `git fetch upstream` on my branch which downloaded some objects. However, when I then do `git status`, it says nothing to commit and is clean. I also tried `git merge master` on the branch but it says already up-to-date.

Comment: fetch does not update your branches locally. Use git pull (which is fetch+merge)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout backend_setup
git merge master
```

should do the trick since your branch seems to be just behind the master. You then should resolve the conflicts locally, which seems to come down to just apply your changes. Then the pull request should work fine after pushing your branch.

Comment: Just tried it to no avail. When I do `git pull` on the master branch, it says it's already up-to-date. Same thing happens when I do `git merge master` on the backend_setup branch. When doing `git status`, it's clean and there doesn't seem to be anything to commit.

Comment: That's strange. Did you try a rebase instead? `git checkout backend_setup`, `git rebase master`. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase